# how to paste several file together using a single space as a delimiter

Tags: paste

These are 3 files:

```
file1   file2   file3
1 2 3   1 1 1   3 3 3
2 1 3   1 1 1   3 3 3
0 0 0   1 1 1   3 3 3
```

I want to join them together and have a final file like:

```
1 2 3 1 1 1 3 3 3
2 1 3 1 1 1 3 3 3
0 0 0 1 1 1 3 3 3
```

But when I use :

```
paste file1 file2 file3 > file4
```

I see gap in output(file4):

```
1 2 3   1 1 1   3 3 3
2 1 3   1 1 1   3 3 3
0 0 0   1 1 1   3 3 3
```

What should I do to not see these gaps?

Comment: Your title is misleading. You want to use a space as a delimiter... I'm retracting my close vote but next time try to find a more suitable title...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried

```
paste -d ' ' file1 file2 file3 > file4
```

and it worked fine.  Tested on MacOS.

Answer (score 3):

Try `paste -d ' ' file1 file2 file3`.  From the manual:

> ```
>  -d list     Use one or more of the provided characters to replace the newline characters
>              instead of the default tab.  The characters in list are used circularly, i.e., when
>              list is exhausted the first character from list is reused.  This continues until a
>              line from the last input file (in default operation) or the last line in each file
>              (using the -s option) is displayed, at which time paste begins selecting characters
>              from the beginning of list again.
>
>              The following special characters can also be used in list:
>
>              \n    newline character
>              \t    tab character
>              \\    backslash character
>              \0    Empty string (not a null character).
>
>              Any other character preceded by a backslash is equivalent to the character itself.
> ```

Comment: Altered to use a space.